# JavaScript imageObj & Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

There is a nested function (a function inside a function) that looks something like this along with some tests that I added:

```
function addImage( ....., borderColor){
   var height;
   var width;
   var imageObj = new Image();
   alert(' just before inner function is: ' + borderColor); 
   imageObj.onload = function(){
      alert(' just after inner function is: ' + borderColor);
```

The first alert shows the correct color, but the second alert is 'null'.

How can I get the variable borderColor inside of the nested function?

Comment: Please show the entire function.

Comment: SLacks, I edited by adding everything up to the second prompt.

Comment: John, Then you have to set the **src** property, otherwise the onload is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[test case here](http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/QAQDf/) it works fine for me

- Are you sure the second alert is the `alert(' just after inner function is: ' + borderColor);` part ?
- Are you sure the variable `borderColor` is not used elsewhere ?
- what browser are you testing on ?

Comment: It was a debugging issue regarding the larger function and as Caspar pointed out imageObj is set after the onload (it had something to do with a line after .src=___ and me not understanding the order of operations. Your comments is what got me thinking and helped fix.

Answer (score 0):

declare the `onload` **first**, but trigger the load **by assigning the source** after that, like wrapping the outer function around the inner function:

```
  function addImage(src, borderColor)
  {
     var pic = new Image();
     pic.onload = function () {
         alert(' just after inner function is: ' + borderColor); 
     }
     alert(' just before inner function is: ' + borderColor); 
     pic.src = src; //<-- this is what you need to set.
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is his issue, he's still getting the alert, but he says it's not scoping correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPdWa/)):

```
function addImage(borderColor){
    var imageObj = new Image();

    alert(' just before inner function is: ' + borderColor);    

    imageObj.addEventListener("load", function() {
        alert(' just after inner function is: ' + borderColor);
    }, false);

    imageObj.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png";
};

addImage("#000000");
```